# SQL query Selecting categories and details without repeating

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am writing a very simple sql query but for some reason I am unable to pull it through. I have mysql table with the following fields; cities, towns and persons. There are several cities, with several towns, which have several people. I want to be able to select a city, say London and be able to see all the towns under london and be able to see everyone living in those towns. What is happening at the moment is that when I query all the tables using their ids, I get a repeat of categories.

I am attaching a picture of what I am trying to achieve
[image]

What I am achieveing is 
city1 -town1 - person1
city1-town 2-person 1

```
   $query = "SELECT *
FROM cities, Transport, town
WHERE cities.id = town.city
AND town.townID = person.townID
GROUP BY cities.cityName"
```

I do not want the city to repeat, but at the same time I want a list of everything in that city

Comment: Can you also include your current query?

Comment: which join are you using? show your query

Comment: So you're OK with the `content` of the result you're getting but not with its `appearance`, right?  If so, you can implement presentation logic in your front end (PHP).

Comment: You would be better off letting the SQL populate all columns, and then do your formatting in PHP (i.e., don't display a cell if the value equals the previous row's value).